# SSRS Parameter: How to change the dropdown to textbox dynamically

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, reporting, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report where there is a dropdownlist parameter which will be populated based on other parameters.

For a particular scenario, when the dropdownlist options are empty, I want to show it as a textbox. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the parameter type dynamically. It is either multi value or not. You could allow nulls (when it is empty) and get your dataset to handle the nulls